# KendoUI Grid server pagination using php

Tags: php, kendo-ui

I want the server side paging in kendo ui using php.So anybody know how to do that?
I have do like serverpaging=true in grid.And for server side logic i need the which page number is selected so i can calculate like pagenumber*perpage and get that records by query.
But how to pass that selected page number to server side?

```
var crudServiceBaseUrl = "<?=base_url()?>",
                 dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                   transport: {
                    read:  {
                        url: crudServiceBaseUrl+"did_grid_list",
                        type:"GET",
                        dataType: "jsonp"
                    },
 serverPaging: true,
 pageSize: 20,
                schema: {
                    total: function(data) { console.log(10034); return 10034; },
                    model: {
                          id: "id",     
                        fields: {
                            did: { validation: { required: true,max:9 } },
                                }
                               }
                             }
                         });
```

above code is my view file.COntroller side is like

```
$json_data = array();
            $count_all = count($this->dids_model->did_get($action));    
        $page_no = $_GET['page']; 

        $json_data['page'] = $page_no;          
        $json_data['total'] = ($count_all>0) ? $count_all : 0;

         $perpage = 20;
         $start = ($page_no-1) * $perpage;
         if($start < 0 )
         $start = 0;
                $result = $this->dids_model->did_get($action,$start,$perpage);
```

Comment: Your problem with pageSize not being sent is because you have incorrect balanced brackets. You have (at least in the code above) a missing "}" for closing `transport`, just before `serverPaging: true,`

Comment: I have already corrected in my real code.I have put just selected code here.thats y one } missing.

Comment: And with the "}" you still don't get the parameters in the server?

Comment: ya not get.I have just print $_GET but in that nothing print.

Answer (score 1):

Please, take a look into [`serverPaging`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#serverpaging-booleandefault) documentation. It shows you the parameters that you will receive in your request referring to:

1. `take`: contains the number of records to retreive
2. `skip`: how many records from the front of the dataset to begin reading
3. `page`: the index of the current page of data
4. `pageSize`: the number of records per page

Comment: i have print the $_GET but in that i have not this parameter.so can you explain how can i got this value on server side?

Comment: Did you set `serverPaging : true` and `pageSize : 10` in the DataSource definition? Can you include in the question what you have so far and I'll take a look?

Comment: yes i have set that.But as you said above parameter that how can i get at server side.I am using the php.So i have GET method but in that above parameter is not come bydefault.

Comment: Would you mind adding to the original question or to JSFiddle what you have so far and I'll take a look into it?

Comment: see my original question.In that $_GET['page'] is not getting anything.

Comment: you have defined the datatype as jsonp and not json

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23148/discussion-between-nency-and-onabai)